# Sql select to show all items with appropriate tags

Tags: sql

I have tables:

```
item(id_item, content) 
tags(id_tag, tag_name) 
items_tags(id_item, id_tag)
```

I have data:

```
item(1, 'content of item')
tags(1, 'bad'), tags(2, 'good'), tags(3, 'best')
items_tags(1, 2), items_tags(1, 3)
```

So in another words item with id 1 has tags good and best.
How to write an sql select to show me all the items that have tags good and best?

Comment: Have you researched anything? Tried writing any of your own code?

Comment: ONLY `good and best` ***or having*** `good and best`? (but could also be bad, rotten, or "they've gone plaid")  `join the tables.  Where tags in (YourList) Group by Item.ID having count(*) = #ofTagsinWhereclause or  replace = #ofTags... with (Select count(distinct Tag_name) from tags where tag_name in ('good','best')`

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple. `join` ,`subquery` and `IN`

```
SELECT *
FROM item i
WHERE i.id_item IN
  (SELECT it.id_item
  FROM items_tags it
  INNER JOIN tags t
  ON it.id_tag      = t.id_tag
  WHERE t.tag_name IN ('good', 'best')
  GROUP BY it.id_item
  HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT t.tag_name) >= 2
  ) t;
```

here's equivalent without subquery:

```
SELECT i.id_item
FROM item i
INNER JOIN items_tags it
ON i.id_item = it.id_item
INNER JOIN tags t
ON it.id_tag      = t.id_tag
WHERE t.tag_name IN ('good', 'best')
GROUP BY i.id_item
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT t.tag_name) >= 2;
```

Comment: This works but only if contains is good enough.  If t.tag_name also included 'Majestic' for these i.id_items but we only wanted those that were just good, best.  Then this wouldn't work but we don't know what the OP wants yet.

Comment: thanks for the answer, although it isnt quite the thing I wanted. This query will search for all items that have tag 'good' or 'best'. And I wanted only items that have both tags 'good' and 'best'

Comment: Subquery isn't necessary now... err outer query (Subquery is all that's really needed now. though it would need the join back to item to get the content.

Comment: i dont't think it works. when i search do this query it outputs 0 results.

Comment: yeah it works just fine I must have mistyped. Thanks for the answers!